# Multiport Netty Socket Server

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I am attempting to develop the following usecase with Netty:

1. Client connects to an intermediary server on (port 8900).
2. Client sends a Processor request with a configuration to another machine.
3. 3rd machine, based on configuration, starts a Processor.
4. Processor connects to the same server which started the processor based on the port identified in the configuration (port 8901, for example).
5. Server now binds Client and Processor based on matching unique hashes shared between the two.
6. New Processors are created for each new Client connection.

The client connection is not a problem. I have a ClientHandler which handles those requests. But I am having a problem registering the ProcessorHandler (which must be bound dynamically based on the configuration sent from the client) and made to serve the specific client.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am currently stumped on how, from ClientHandler, once the configuration for a processor is sent, I could start a new server socket on the server and link the client to it's processor.

Client and processor share a unique hash number which can be used to identify which processor should server which client.

I've basically been using [Netty HexProxy Example](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/proxy/package-summary.html) idea, but instead of a client socket, I need another server socket to serve the processor. I was thinking of linking the two by either adding a handler to the other's pipe or doing something similar to [Netty SecureChat Example](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/securechat/package-frame.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By re-imagining the scenario I was able to solve this problem.

Instead of thinking of a Client as a client and a Processor as a server serving the requests of a specific client I treat both as clients connecting to a chat server (the intermediary server).

Arbitrary server ports are established by sending the bootstrap into a HandshakeHandler which binds and syncs ports which are not currently bound.

It is also the HandshakeHandler which, via the unique hash, connects Clients and Processors into a specific ChannelGroup and reconfigures channel pipelines for each channel as required (removing itself once the handshake between Client and Processor have completed successfully).